# How does Stack Overflow's search compare with Google's site-specific search?

Tags: discussion, search

When I search Stack Overflow, I usually do it with Google's `site:stackoverflow.com` flag.

If I only do basic search, how would you say Stack Overflow's inner search engine compares to the site-specific Google search?

Comment: Someone will have to confirm this, but I think the SO search only looks at body of posts, not comments.  Google probably catches comments too, for better or worse.

Comment: make sure you're aware of the advanced search options at http://stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 7):

SO's search has a lot of limitations, which I won't go into here.

A standard Google search (as has been previously mentioned) searches everything, but it's easy enough to tell Google to not do that. Here's the query:

```
 yourKeywords site:stackoverflow.com/questions -inurl:tagged -inurl:meta
```

So if you wanted to search `stackoverflow.com` for `unicorns`, you just need to look for:

```
 unicorns site:stackoverflow.com/questions -inurl:tagged -inurl:meta
```

[Try it yourself!](http://www.google.com/search?q=unicorns+site:stackoverflow.com/questions+-inurl:tagged+-inurl:meta)

Comment: what's the point of `-inurl:meta`? it's already scoped to a specific domain via `site:`

Comment: @Jeff - When you search the `stackoverflow.com` domain, by default, you also get `meta.stackoverflow.com` questions. The good news is that it makes SE2.0 network-wide searches really easy: just swap in `stackexchange.com/questions`.

Comment: @Dori Would using `www.stackoverflow.com` restrict it to the main site?

Comment: Those sub-domains (that's what they're called right?) like the `plus` in `plus.google.com` are dedicated servers for that part of the site, yeah? So does `www.` mean that only the 'general' or 'main' serves get to handle the data?

Comment: Why was `www.` ever required? Isn't `http://stackoverflow.com` enough? What's the point of it? The `http` (that's the scheme, right?) specifies the protocol...

Answer (score 4):

I find it difficult to find questions/answers I know I've seen before using the SO search unless I remember exactly a unique phrase that I can search in quotes `"like so"`.  The ordering of results is bad without this, I usually see unrelated or tangentially related results first.  I mostly search on Android Enthusiasts, though, so things could be better on SO.

Perhaps it's because I have years of experience getting Google to spit out what I want, but I don't have the same issue with Google.  If my first attempt at search doesn't have what I need in the first few results (rarely), my second or third search does.  Not so with the search here.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the google search it seems to search **EVERYWHERE** on SO.

That includes -

- Questions
- Answers
- Comments
- Tags
- User pages
- The List goes on and on...

Comment: But in practice, do you find it's better or worse? I never got anything but a question page when I Googled SO.

Comment: @ripper234 -- see here: http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20testing&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=44a088bb012dd74b&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=dc6bfd13aa3475fb&biw=1680&bih=965&ion=1 I searched **`testing`**

Comment: I guess I internally filter those results. I actually think it's nice to find a tag page, but I agree user pages are pretty worthless. The reason I like Google so much is for its "other features", like spell correction. Just compare http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=heruku to http://www.google.co.il/search?q=heruku+site%3Astackoverflow.com