# When searching is it better to use the built-in SO search or use Google?

Tags: discussion, search, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow's search compare with Google's site-specific search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107211/how-does-stack-overflows-search-compare-with-googles-site-specific-search)

I find sometimes when I used the built-in search I don't find the result I'm looking for but I find it when I search site:stackoverflow on Google.

What is the more recommended way to search SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick you engine based on your needs and their strengths.  For plain text search Google beats SE's search handily.  But if you want to search for questions tagged with a few particular tags and at least X views and Y votes, you'll want to use SE's search, since Google has no idea what tags or views or votes are.

Answer (score 2):

Use whatever method *you* find most effective.  I'm partial to using the built-in search, as it is easier to limit your query to tag categories using the `[tagname]` syntax.

For example to require that the result be in the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag:

```
[php] expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given
```

... thousands of duplicates appear...

Occasionally I'll be looking for one of my own previous answers, wherein the `user:userid` syntax is quite handy. Obviously this is less useful for finding others' answsers in a targeted way unless you first visit their profiles to find their userids.

```
[php] user:541091 expects parameter 1 to be resource boolean given
```